# How do I change a website's default viewport settings in a mobile browser on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

A website works well in Landscape mode. But when turned to Portrait mode, it shows the message "Screen size not supported". I tried to emulate it in my desktop browser and found that changing `initial-scale:1` to `initial-scale:0.6` in the meta tag in website's HTML did the trick. Now, how to do this on the fly in my iPad? Is there any extension that I can use?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what is the problem in your code since you didn't post any, but maybe CSS Media Queries will do the trick.
let's say:

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
   initial-scale:0.6
}
```

you can learn more on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: It's not my website. I'm actually trying to open a third party website in Portrait mode on my iPad.

Comment: Well, if the developers of that website didn't take care of the compatibility of other devices I'm not sure there is so much to do. I did find a Chrome extension that I hope will help you 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh/related

Comment: I could achieve it in desktop using greasemonkey or tampermonkey extensions. But those are not available for ios devices.